# How to navigate after submit a form in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

Here is my action creator :

```
export const signInByPhone = ({ phone })=>{
 console.log('All props : ', this.props); // no props are coming. ??  
    return (dispatch) => {        
        fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                phone_no : phone
            })
        })
        .then((res) =>res.json())
        .then((jsonRes) =>{
            if (jsonRes.code === 200) {
                console.log('json response code1 : ', jsonRes);
                // go to verification screen                                                                     
                generatOTPSuccess(dispatch,jsonRes);
            }
            else { // reset otp sending screen  
                console.log('json response code2 : ', jsonRes);
            }
        }) 
        .catch(res => generatOTPFail(dispatch, res));
    };    
}
```

Helper methods :

```
const generatOTPSuccess = (dispatch, res) =>{   
    dispatch({
        type: 'OTP_GENERATE_SUCCESS',
        payload: res
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate('OtpVerify');  
  // Error : payload: TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of 
          undefined at generatOTPSuccess                                 
}
```

What I want to achieve , once the OTP generate successfully, It should navigate to VerifyScreen. 
Which I am not able to do. Can you anyone say to what could be the possible ways ?

On button click , I have passed following :

```
onButtonPress(){         
        const {phone}=this.props;
  console.log(phone, " :  this.props : ",this.props); // all props r coming
        this.props.signInByPhone({ phone });        
    }
```

Comment: According to the error message you are not able to get this.props. Can you console this.props and check if it gives undefined ?

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer generateOTPSuccess doesn't have access to your components' this.props

There are 3 ways I know of to do this, the OTP_GENERATE_SUCCESS (and OTP_GENERATE_FAIL) action must change some state so you could pass that state to your component and issue the this.props.navigation.navigate('OtpVerify') call in your component when you see the change (at a guess in componentWillUpdate)

The second way is to pass a callback to the action creator like this.

```
class Example extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        ....   // constructor code
        this.onSuccess = this.onSuccess.bind(this); 
        // this makes sure that this points to the component when it's ran in the action creator

    }

    ....  // component code

    onSuccess()
    {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('OtpVerify');
    }

    handleSubmit(e, loginDetails)
    {
        this.signInByPhone(loginDetails, this.onSuccess);
    }
}
```

Then I'd change the action creator to take an onSuccess callback

```
export const signInByPhone = ({ phone }, onSuccess)=>{
    return (dispatch) => {        
        fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                phone_no : phone
            })
        })
        .then((res) =>res.json())
        .then((jsonRes) =>{
            if (jsonRes.code === 200) {
                console.log('json response code1 : ', jsonRes);
                // go to verification screen                                                                     
                generatOTPSuccess(dispatch,jsonRes);
                if(typeof(onSuccess) === 'function')
                {
                    onSuccess();
                }
            }
            else { // reset otp sending screen  
                console.log('json response code2 : ', jsonRes);
            }
        }) 
        .catch(res => generatOTPFail(dispatch, res));
    };    
}
```

And change generateOTPSuccess to

```
const generatOTPSuccess = (dispatch, res) =>{   
    dispatch({
        type: 'OTP_GENERATE_SUCCESS',
        payload: res
    });
 }
```

The third way is to return the promise from the fetch and handle it in the component

```
class Example extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        ....   // constructor code
    }

    .... //  component code

    onSuccess()
    {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('OtpVerify');
    }

    onFail()
    {
        ... // handle a fail
    }


    handleSubmit(e)
    {
        this.signInByPhone(loginDetails).then(this.onSuccess, this.onFail);
    }
}
```

And change signInByPhone to return the promise

```
export const signInByPhone = ({ phone }, onSuccess)=>{
    return (dispatch) => {        
        return fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
        .... 
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more, what did you change and what errors are you getting now?

Answer (score 0):

Use `OTP_GENERATE_SUCCESS` and `OTP_GENERATE_FAIL` action to change payload value or add error in state of login so you could pass that state to your component and issue the `this.props.navigation.navigate('OtpVerify')` call in your component's `componentWillReceiveProps` method.

For example you have a login redux than

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.loggedIn) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('OtpVerify');  
    } else if (!newProps.attempting && newProps.error) {
      showMessage(newProps.error);
    }
  }


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    loggedIn: !!state.login.payload,
    error: state.login.error,
    attempting: state.login.attempting
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

and your reducer will have logic something like that on different actions it will update state in the following way

```
// login attempts
const attempt = (state, action) =>
  state.merge({attempting: true});

// successful logins
const success = (state, action) =>
  state.merge({attempting: false, error: null, payload: action.payload});

// login failure
const failure = (state, action) =>
  state.merge({attempting: false, error: action.error});
```